# slideToggle Div and Rotate Icon if visible or hidden

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slidetoggle

If you click on a div, I want the target "panel" to slideToggle(). If the target panel is hidden, I want to add a class to a glyphicon which will spin it 270 degrees.

I've got everything working except the check for visible is failing. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).delegate(".showhide", "click", function(e) {
  var panel = $(this).attr('panel');
  $("#" + panel).slideToggle();
  var icon = $(this).attr('icon');

  if ($("#" + panel).is(":visible")) {
    $("#" + icon).removeClass('gly-rotate-270');
  } else {
    $("#" + icon).addClass('gly-rotate-270');
  }
});
```

```css
.gly-rotate-270 {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showhide" panel="panelskills" icon="skillsicon">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" id="skillsicon"></span> Skill Level
</div>

<div id="panelskills">
  Some content in here...
</div>
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvc3s0ug/)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try to console log the panel if it really points to a panel

Comment: Yes, thank you, the "panel" variable points to the "panelskills" div.

Comment: `panel `and `icon` are attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

- Trimmed down the HTML
- For rotation of icon use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)`('glyphicon-circle-arrow-down glyphicon-circle-arrow-right')`;
- Change `panel` and `icon` to `data-panel` and `data-icon`
- Change `.attr()` to [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

`panel` and `icon` are not attributes. `data-panel` and `data-icon` are valid and the values are strings which is exactly what you need. [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is the recommended method to use with [`data-*` attributes](http://www.thecreativedev.com/how-to-use-html5-data-attributes/).

Also `.delegate()` is deprecated use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('.showhide').on("click", function(e) {
  var panel = $(this).data('panel');
  console.log(panel);
  var icon = $(this).data('icon');
  console.log(icon);

  $("#" + panel).slideToggle();
  $("#" + icon).toggleClass('glyphicon-circle-arrow-down glyphicon-circle-arrow-right');

});
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down" id="skillsicon"></span>  <a href='#/' class="showhide" data-panel="panelskills" data-icon="skillsicon">Skill Level</a>


<div id="panelskills">
  Some content in here...
</div>
```

Comment: you just taught me the correct way to do a few things including data() and on(). That's ingenious. I'm going to be using them often. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

HI Bro try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pvc3s0ug/11/

Change your js like this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
    $(document).delegate(".showhide", "click", function(e) {

      var panel = $(this).attr('panel');

      $("#" + panel).slideToggle();

      var icon = $(this).attr('icon');
     $("#"+ icon).toggleClass('gly-rotate-270');

    });
 });
```

Comment: and zer00ne you guys are both correct. I should be using the toggleClass, much better. Totally fixed it. Thanks!